# What does "stomp away" mean?

Tags: meaning

I know the meaning of the *stomp*, but I want to know what the meaning of *stomp away* is.

I found [this GIF](http://makeagif.com/dtE2nI) for it. Does it mean: to go with a stomping manner?

Comment: Without more context it's difficult to answer your question. I suspect your referring to [this definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stomp): to ​walk with ​intentionally ​heavy ​steps, ​especially as a way of ​showing that you are ​annoyed: Example "I hate you!' were the only words that stumbled from his trembling mouth as he blubbered and stomped away"

Comment: @Christopher tnx for you attention, no, I want the meaning of **stomp away**

Comment: ,and I have given you a definition and an example usage, further context is required. For "stomp away" take the definition of stomp in my first comment and away as in move away from here.. go from here. The example I've given above is in the past tense, which is why its "stomped"

Comment: If "Fred turned and stomped away" then that is what he did -- stomp in an away direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to walk away, usually moodily, stomping one's feet. Usually accompanied by slamming a door...!